# Working with more than one dummy variable in neural net

Tags: neural-network

I am building a neural net and am at the point of working with categorical variables.   Below you can see that I transformed the categorical variables into numeric variables.

```
#Encode "UserName"
labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 0] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 0])
#Encode "Token"
labelencoder_X_2 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = labelencoder_X_2.fit_transform(X[:, 1])
#Encode "ChildEXE"
labelencoder_X_3 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 3] = labelencoder_X_3.fit_transform(X[:, 3])
#Encode "ParentEXE"
labelencoder_X_4 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 4] = labelencoder_X_4.fit_transform(X[:, 4])
#Encode "ChildFilePath"
labelencoder_X_5 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 5] = labelencoder_X_5.fit_transform(X[:, 5])
#Encode "ParentFilePath"
labelencoder_X_6 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 6] = labelencoder_X_6.fit_transform(X[:, 6])
```

Now I am supposed to transform any that have more than 2.  For instance "UserName" has "Machine Name", "User", and "Local Service".  "Token" has about 10 options, "ChildEXE" has thousands etc.

```
X
array([[2, 0, 20788, ..., 46, 31, 24],        
[2, 0, 19088, ..., 46, 31, 24],        
[2, 0, 2840, ..., 27, 42, 15],       
 ...,        
[2, 0, 20148, ..., 17, 40, 32],        
[2, 0, 20148, ..., 47, 23, 0],        
[2, 0, 3176, ..., 48, 42, 32]], dtype=object)
```

Do I use the code below several times for each variable that has more that 2?

```
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that this works:

```
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0,1,3,4,5,6])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```